# joining tables, query by date, sum fields and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables (`fuel` and `bus_mileage`). The common denominator is the bus name.

I need to do a query of total amount of miles done and the fuel usage by bus and date.

table(`fuel`) has these fields

- ID
- bus
- date
- litres
- net
- VAT
- Gross

table (`bus_mileage`) has these fields

- id
- bus
- date
- trip
- service
- start_mileage
- end_mileage
- nailsea_user
- clevedon_user
- portishead_user
- other_user
- total_miles
- total_journeys

My query:

```
SELECT
  f.ID,
  f.bus,
  f.litres,
  f.Gross,
  fuel,
  b.id,
  b.bus,
  b.total_miles,
  b.total_journeys bus_mileage SUM(total_miles) as 'total_miles',
  SUM(total_miles * 1.60) as 'total KM',
  (SUM(portishead_user) + SUM(clevedon_user) + SUM(nailsea_user) + SUM(other_user)) as 'Total Journeys' SUM(litres) as 'fuel Litres',
  SUM(Gross) as 'Gross Value',
  SUM(net) as 'Net Value',
  SUM(VAT) as 'VAT Value',
  (SUM(litres) / SUM(Gross)) as 'Total MPG'
FROM fuel f
INNER JOIN bus_mileage b on f.bus = b.bus
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2020-03-31'
group by bus
```

Comment: Show us what code you tried.

Comment: Helo Ant Lingham, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question will be much clearer if you provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text.

Comment: SELECT 
f.ID,
f.bus,
f.litres,
f.Gross,
fuel,
b.id,
b.bus,
b.total_miles,
b.total_journeys bus_mileage
SUM(total_miles) as 'total_miles',
   SUM(total_miles * 1.60) as 'total KM',
   (SUM(portishead_user) + SUM(clevedon_user) + SUM(nailsea_user) + SUM(other_user)) as 'Total Journeys'
SUM(litres) as 'fuel Litres',
   SUM(Gross) as 'Gross Value',
   SUM(net) as 'Net Value',
   SUM(VAT) as 'VAT Value',
   (SUM(litres) / SUM(Gross)) as 'Total MPG'
FROM
fuel f 
INNER JOIN bus_mileage b on f.bus = b.bus WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2020-03-31' group by bus

Comment: Your question and your query do not match -- there are lots of columns not mentioned in the question.  That makes it hard to answer because it is unclear what you are really asking about.

Comment: GMB's code works great but how do i add a between dates as this needs to be a 6 monthly report

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each table has more than one row per bus and date, the base idea is to aggregate in subqueries, then join them together.

Something like:

```
select f.bus, f.bus_date, f.fuel_usage, m.mileage 
from (
    select bus, date(fuel_date) bus_date, sum(litres) fuel_usage
    from fuel f
    group by bus, date(fuel_date)
) f
inner join (
    select bus, date(mileage_date) bus_date, sum(end_mileage - start_mileage) mileage
    from bus_mileage m
    group by bus, date(mileage_date)
) m
    on f.bus = m.bus and f.bus_date = m.bus_date
```

I renamed the `date` columns so it is more obvious what they are - and I assumed that they actually are of `datetime` datatype.

Comment: would it be useful if i did rename the columns to mileage_date and bus_date?

Comment: @AntLingham: no, not necessarily. I found that it just made the query easier to understand, but you can change that to the actual column names.

Comment: Would there be a way of adding a date query to this? I would like to run the coded between two dates ie first to last of current month

Comment: @AntLingham: you can add a `where` clause to each subquery, like `where date >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') and date < date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 1 month`

Comment: Hi, how would i create the query so it only shows one result for bus but sums the values from litres and total_miles